# Change site's title to match Google search

Tags: php, html, seo

I was developing a site for a parts distributor, when I ran into an SEO problem.

Basically, the business distributes many different brands, so I want to make it that, when a certain brand is searched, the title of the google result changes to that particular brand.

Example:

If Brand-X is searched on google, the result should appear as...

My Business - Brand-X distributor

I want it to lead to the same page though. Is there any valid way to do this, or will I have to settle with setting keywords for each of the brands, and a site description including them?

Comment: you should create a Google Sitemap for that - http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156184

Answer (score 3):

> I want it to lead to the same page though.

That isn't possible. Google will show the title of the page at the time it was indexed.

Comment: If you have a db of brands I'd make a dynamic landing page and make sure they're indexed from your sitemap.  That way at least you do have a page with each brand in the title for SEO preference

Answer (score 1):

Google indexes your pages first, and when someone searches google, they look in their index.  The results they display are from their cached version, and not a live fetch from your site.  Hope that clears things up.

Answer (score 0):

Naah No Such way to play with Titles for search Engines!

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the title in the HTML

```
<title>My Business - Brand-X distributor</title>
```

Google will display the title of the page for each webpage in the results.

Google will eventually reindex the page and show the new title.

Comment: Sounds like the TC wants a way to do this programmatically, rather than going through each page and altering the title by hand.

Answer (score 0):

...actually it is possible but it will require some work. I just finished something similar. Google accesses your page content very much the same as any other visitor so you need to actually create an illusion that each product have it's own page (even thought all is aiming to your product-id123.php for example). So you need to start with a page which will contain the list of every product you have and then generate dynamically a unique link for each of them.

This can be done by a simple PHP loop accessing an array of all the products and creating a link + title for each of them.

You will end-up with a very long page and it is better (if you have thousands of products) to separate this into separate pages based on the product category for example.

Then when you have all the product list pages done you can use the following script in the header of the main landing page.

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/product-id123.php') {
$title = '<title>Product ID 123</title>';
} elseif ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/product-id456.php') {
$title = '<title>Product ID 456</title>';   // etc...


?>
```